# Char array indexes not accepting

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, null, char, incompatibility

I'm having an issue with a mock game of Tic tac toe. I'm using a two-dimensional array to represent the playing board, and have instantiated it as follows. It's required that I use a char type array. I realize that I shouldn't have to specify that each index is null, as that's the default for char, but I thought I would give it a try.

```
public TicTacToe2D()
{
    board = new char[3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
        {
            board[j] = null;
        }

        board[i] = null;
    }         
}
```

Here I'm checking for a win condition, seeing if indexes are equal to each other and not null (the default) though I have attempted using ' ' for my array initial value. In that case I got the error: "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to char[]"

```
public char isWin()
{
    //Check for row wins
    if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2] && board[0][0] != null)
        return true;

    if (board[1][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[1][2] && board[1][0] != null)
        return true;

    if (board[2][0]==board[2][1] && board[2][1]==board[2][2] && board[2][0] != null)
        return true;

    //Check for column wins
    if (board[0][0]==board[1][0] && board[1][0]==board[2][0] && board[0][0] != null)
        return true; 

    if (board[0][1]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][1] && board[0][1] != null)
        return true; 

    if (board[0][2]==board[1][2] && board[1][2]==board[2][2] && board[0][2] != null)
        return true; 

    //Check for diagonal wins
    if (board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2] && board[0][0] != null)
        return true; 

    if (board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2] && board[2][0] != 0)
        return true; 
    else return false;
}
```

When checking if an index is null I get the error "incomparable types: char and "
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Char is primitive type, so it can't be null, it's `'\u0000'` on default which is 0.

Comment: Also what you do here `board[j] = null;` is that you set each "row" of your array to null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype `char` is primitive, so it can't be `null`.  But the default value is the null *character*, `\0` (or `\u0000`).  [JLS Section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) gives default values:

> - For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.

Try comparing it to `\0` or `\u0000` instead of `null`.

Comment: Thank you! Comparing to the null character resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

a char is not an object, it's a primitive type.

that means that a char is like an integer, or float, or Boolean, that have a fixed length and its initial value is *zero* (or false).

As far as I remember char is an 8bit, but I might be wrong. Said all that, a char you can compare to a letter, for example: `'a'` or with an actual number, for example `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`board` is declared as `char[][]`. It is thus an array of char arrays. So `board[i]` is a char array (a row of your board). And `board[i][j]` is a char (the value of a cell of your board).

The default value of each cell of such a 2D array is 0. Not null. A primitive type can't be null.